# Android custom header

Tags: android

I am trying to replicate the `actionBar/header`(The blue area) for my app. I would like it to do exactly what is done in that image, except the last icon on the right I would prefer to be the menu (three dots)

After doing some research people have used `AcitonBarActivity` and customized the `acitonBar`, but that was deprecated since April 2015. Looking further into this, people have suggested to use `Toolbar` and actionBar is a subset of that.

Now I am don't know where to start. All I want to do is replicate the header area in the image below.

Note: The app right now only extends `Activity` and not `ActionBarActivity`. Also I will be building with minimum version `Ice cream sandwhich (4.0)`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try to extend AppCompatActivity and use Toolbar.

here is reference site.

http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/android-design-support-library-codelab/en

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the new `Appcompat` and `Design` library that google has to offer.

You can start by added this in your gradle dependencies in your app:

`compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'`

When you are ready you can go to this [sample project](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/support/android/designlibdemo/MainActivity.java) and the [link documentation](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) for each new design widgets.

On what you want is easy to make just create a layout that wraps the `toolbar` in `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, just follow the sample project.

Comment: After looking into this and building a sample project, I can see that the collapsing tool bar requires 'NestedSrollView' which does not work for pre lollipop devices without RecyclerView. This was a problem for me since my project is built on ListView for now. I decided to use ActionBar with a custom height and some other styles applied to it.